# Assistive Technology for Snake People with Anosmia

Tags: fantasy-races, medieval, disabilities

If a snake-person, which we'll say is a human with a snake's face and senses, could not smell (the vomeronasal organ doesn't work), what technologies could be made to replace this sense's usual functions? Able-bodied snake-people use their sense of smell to detect obstacles and identity others, as their sense of sight is poor. They are also deaf. The world has roughly medieval european technology

Comment: Um... snakes smell with their tongue so that's what they'd use

Comment: @Firestryke I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: Well, technically snakes don't smell the way we do, they "taste" scents and smell that way.

Comment: There seems to be confusion about what's meant by "smell". Do you mean their nasal passage's sense organs don't exist/work, or do you mean their Jacobson's organ in their mouth (the one the tongue flicks in and out to) doesn't work? (Or both)

Comment: Ichthys, I strongly recommend that you delete this question, then [read this article](https://www.pressconnects.com/story/news/2017/03/02/why-do-snakes-smell-their-tongue/98629464/). If it doesn't answer this question, it will set you up to ask a better question. Cheers.

Comment: @IchthysKing Are you asking about a *disabled* snake-person? As in, normally the snake person is supposed to have a sense of smell similar to a snake but this particular snake person has anosmia so they can't perceive chemicals in the air in the same sense other snake people do?

Comment: Are we counting 'trained dog' as a technology?

Comment: @MolbOrg What do you mean?

Comment: ah yeah, sorry wrong comment, didn't notice(didn't know the word). what makes it possible in your setting? this snake elephant people is irrelevant information? or is it relevant then what makes it relevant to the q you currently have? what do you expect to get as an answer in "medieval european technology"? To which extent the prosthesis should work, maybe which smells it should detect. or are you looking for some physical principle on which you can handwave a technology and add it to your setting? idk, it looks like this q needs some improvement work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cane, hat, service animal.**

http://www.bl.uk/catalogues/illuminatedmanuscripts/ILLUMIN.ASP?Size=mid&IllID=32758

[image: blind medieval man]

found linked from http://www.larsdatter.com/blind.htm

Your anosmic snake person is the equivalent of a blind person.  The snake person will dress or be marked in such a way that other persons with normal senses understand the disability and extend extra consideration.  If you know a person is blind you will not assume she will get out of your way or recognize you from a distance.  You might extend your assistance to the person if appropriate.

A service animal can be helpful.  Your anosmic snake people could associate with service animals to help them navigate their worlds.

Tactile sensation can substitute for visual and perhaps olfactory senses.  This medieval blind person carries a cane as some blind people do today.  A broad brimmed hat makes sense as impediments situated to hit the face might not be felt by the cane, but could be intercepted by the brim of the hat.  If a snake person has no hands to hold a cane the hat could serve double duty with an extra big brim, and look styling as well.  Illustrations very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Snake’s eyesight isn’t the best by any means since their world is made of smells, but you still could give them glasses or enhancement lenses so that they can rely on a different sensorial sphere to navigate life. Second option, a ‘smelling service dog’, or another animal that can be trained to alert the owner of different smells, for example making the presence of a friend or prey known to them.

Comment: Hi Archivist. The dog was already proposed in the other, accepted answer. Please take our [Tour] to familiarize yourself with this platform. Welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: Had you perhaps meant to leave this as a comment? You'll be able to leave those on other's posts when you've enough [reputation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). In addition to the tour recommended by Joachim, glance at our [help] for guidance and info about our ways. Welcome to Worldbuilding.